# Find Record in Recordset SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I am using classic asp to produce a website and am using the below SQL statement, the database is SQL Server 2000.

```
SELECT * from dbo.PDBproductview where product LIKE '" & partnumbersearch   &"%';"
```

However we now also require forward and back buttons to move forward and backwards by part number - not sure how to achieve this - my initial thought was to run another sql query and somehow get the placement of the part in the part table (product) then to pick out the part before and after it, is it possible to do  this ?

Comment: You need to parameterize your queries instead of building up a string like this. What you have is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: can you please give an example ?

Comment: The best examples can be found using a search engine...https://www.google.com/search?q=classic+asp+parameterized+query&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to solve the actual question I asked ?

Comment: The problem Emma is that your question is entirely too vague to provide an answer. There just aren't any details here. The topic of creating a scrolling logic through a resultset is far more than an online forum can provide. What have you tried? Do you have any of this working? What part(s) do you need help with? The only actual question you posted is "is it possible to do this?". The answer is "Yes it is possible".

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what version of SQL Server you are using. However, if you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher, the LEAD and LAG functions will allow you to achieve what you want to do.

Here is a pretty good [article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/) you can use as a guide. Essentially it looks something like this:

```
SELECT LAG(p.FirstName) OVER (ORDER BY p.BusinessEntityID) PreviousValue,
p.FirstName, LEAD(p.FirstName) OVER (ORDER BY p.BusinessEntityID) NextValue
FROM Person.Person p
```

With the LEAD and LAG functions, you can indicate how far back or forward you want to look.